# Crawling a website fails because javascript isn't enabled

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

I use Abot for crawling,

I want to crawl a website that appears to block any request that doesn't have javascript enabled 
it's a php page, and i get a "Please activate javascript to view this site." instead of the real site

How does a page know if javascript is enabled or not? (and in your opinion - do you think i can overcome that?)

Thanks

Comment: Is it failing to download the site or is it failing to display it properly? Its more likely this error is being generated client-side, not coming directly from the server. But of course most crawlers will fail to download content generated at runtime by scripts.

Comment: Afaik the only way the server can know you have JavaScript disabled is by running something like `document.cookie = 'me_has_javascript=1';` and check if this cookie is present in the subsequent HTTP requests.

Comment: I am getting a page , just a page saying i need javascript enabled, i'm guessing they use Ajax to load the page...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you crawl the site with a javascript-enabled client, you are out of luck.

Comment: Where can i find a client like that?

Comment: @RoyiM Well, you well probably need to investigate various UI testing tools which can provide such support.